# How to design report at run time SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-designer

most of the time we point store procedure or table and then SSRS report designer show us field and we just drag drop those field on to report designer surface. after all we call those report programmatically and pass parameter and report shown on report viewer.

now my company want that customer will customize the report who will see the report. they want to display all the fields in a form and just customer will select each field and place on report designer surface and give some input like filter condition like date range or employee id etc and report will be shown. also at run time if customer want they can add text or move existing field etc.

i do not have any idea how could i do this with SSRS. if this is possible with SSRS then please guide me in such a way as a result i can start the job or if possible give me few relevant url of that kind from where i can get the idea. thanks

Comment: http://www.fyireporting.com/download.html

Comment: I know it's old post but can you share if you solve this ? I'm using rdl files and i want allow users a basic runtime design functionality,like adding some new columns available or renaming etc

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is capable of reading reports generated on-the-fly, but they have to be made just right. SSRS reports are XML documents that specify the data structure and report object structures and how the two are related. Using Visual Studio, you can use certain classes to create the XML document which is then read & filled with data on the server, then exported to the client as a standard webpage.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170667%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a link to a tutorial. This should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small but working example of generating RDL on-the-fly with some useful links to MSDN documentation: ["How to dynamically generate SSRS Report in Code"](http://www.kudinov.ru/?p=106)

Hope it helps!